# Python 3. Написал код, но не знаю как запустить

Tags: python

Есть написанный код:

```
x = input("what is the capital of Russia? ")
if x != 'Moscow':
  print("Not at all!")
x = input("What is the capital of Russia? ")
if x == 'Moscow':
  print("Great answer!")
```

Как мне его запустить? Ну чтобы мне задавал задачу, я писал ответ, а он отвечал мне??

Comment: на какой операцоинной системе вы работаете? GNU/Linux: `chmod +x script.py; ./script.py` или `python ./script.py` если win убедитесь что Python установлен.

Comment: я на линуксе, питон включен. то что вы написали как применить то?

Comment: Откройте терминал. Как давно вы поставили и какой дистрибутив?

Comment: ну открыл, питон 3.6.7 включил. дальше что?

Comment: `python путь/к/файлу.py` в терминале

Comment: я не понимаю! руководитель говорил что никакие редакторы кода не нужны будут как минимум еще 3 занятия. значит и этот код должен был быть записан в терминале и сразу же работать без каких либо путей к файлу

Comment: @Mafakagroov https://opentechschool.github.io/python-beginners/ru/getting_started.html#using-python

Comment: Вопрос у вас интересный. "Есть написанный код" где, в чем, как он написан, что вы запускаете под именем питон 3.6.7? Если он на бумаге - увы запустить ни как не выйдет еще лет 100 :)

Comment: небольшая правка на счёт кода, лучше всего объедить 3 и 6 строки через if/else, и код будет выглядить так, 
capital_of_Russia = input('what is the capital of Russia? ')
moscow = 'Moscow'
if capital_of_Russia == moscow:
 print("Great answer!")
else:
 print('Not at all!')

Comment: Преждем чем стать программистом, надо стать уверенным пользователем ПК.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно открыть терминал, дальше не запуская `Python` прописать такие команды:

```bash
cd путь/к/скрипту #папка в которой лежит скрипт
chmod +x имя_файла.py #подставляем Ваше имя скрипта
python3 имя_файла.py
```

Все! Еще совет, как правильно написать Ваш код (с использованием `if-else`):

```py
x = input('What is the capital of Russia? ')

if x == 'Moscow':
    print('Great answer!')
else:
    print('Not at all!')
```

Answer (score -3):

Один из вариантов:

```
while True:
    x = input("what is the capital of Russia? ")
    if x == 'q':
        break
    if x == 'Moscow':
        print("Great answer!")
    else:
        print("Not at all!")
```

Comment: Вы точно прочитали вопрос?

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос топикстартера, он о другом спрашивал.

Comment: Вопрос был о том, как запустить скрипт, а не исправить код